# Issue when retrieving number field from a record to display in Lightning component with decimal values

Tags: numbers, decimal, field

The number field (6, 12) when retrived from apex to display in lwc component when three digits are there in the field its returning without decimal values but above 4 values it is retuning 12 '0' decimal values. it is woking fine when it is displayed using input type number but in text input it is displaying 12 '0' decimal values

If it is a standard behaviour for 3 digits also the decimal values should come

Answer (score 0):

From the question

If you can process the data in js you can always use .toFixed(**decimalPlaces**)

decimalPlaces : for eg. 2 to get always 2 digits after decimal

and then convert it to string by .toString()

for better understanding could you provide the code as well